# simple form dropdown with search or autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple form with a dropdown of items that it's very long. I would like to know if there is a way to make a search bar with an autocomplete for these items or a dropdown with a search bar that looks for items in the dropdown as you search.

Comment: You can include a library like selectize.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is the same as the below question please check it. you can get a solution to your problem.

[Ruby on Rails - Simple Form autocomplete association search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779009/ruby-on-rails-simple-form-autocomplete-association-search)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the select2-rails gem to search from the dropdown.Here is the github link [Click](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)